# Checking if selected layer is poly line or point in ArcObjects C#?

Tags: arcobjects

My TOC contains two layers one polyline and point.

If i selected polyline layer  execute the polyline related code..else if selected layer is point execute the point related code.

How do I get Selected layer point or polyline in ArcObjects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the geometry type of a layer you must first cast to an [IFeatureLayer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000004tp000000) then from the [IFeatureLayer.FeatureClass](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000004w7000000) you can access the [ShapeType](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000002tp000000) property:

```
// Assuming your input layer is of type ILayer and ILayer.Valid is true
IFeatureLayer FLayer = (IFeatureLayer)YourLayer; 
if (FLayer.FeatureClass.ShapeType == esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPoint)
{
    // do you stuff for points
}
else if (FLayer.FeatureClass.ShapeType == esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolyline)
{
    // do you stuff for lines
}
```

Note that although a [geometry type constant](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m0000001p000000) exists for Line this is not the same as PolyLine; Line feature classes have a shape type of esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolyline. The geometry type enum is used for more than just the shape type of a feature class so it contains geometry types that *cannot* be used as a geometry storage for a feature class (eg path, ring).